# How to scalably refresh Core Data objects that have derived attributes after viewContext.save()

Tags: swiftui, core-data

My SwiftUI Core Data app extensively uses relationship derived attributes such as `.@count` and `.@sum`. These values are displayed to the user using SwiftUI views that get their data from attributes of `@ObservedObject`s. Calling `viewContext.save()` updates all non-derived members of the `@ObservedObject`s, but not the derived members, which is expected [per the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription?language=swift). Without any additional logic these views would show inconsistent, partially stale data to users.

I have been addressing this by asynchronously refreshing all objects after `viewContext.save()` by calling `viewContext.refreshAllObjects()` after every `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange` notification. Code below. However this seems to scale very badly, because I could be refreshing 100s of objects on every save.

What's a scalable way to refresh objects that have derived attributes? Should I collect all `viewContext.updatedObjects` and `viewContext.insertedObjects` just before each `viewContext.save()` so that I can refresh them right after each save?

Is this approach more scalable?

```
func saveThenRefresh(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws {
    let entitiesToRefresh = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

    let objectsToProcess = context.insertedObjects.union(context.updatedObjects)

    let filteredObjects = objectsToProcess.filter { object in
        guard let entityName = object.entity.name else { return false }
        return entitiesToRefresh.contains(entityName)
    }

    try context.save()
    
    for object in filteredObjects {
        context.refresh(object, mergeChanges: true)
    }
}
```

Code I'm currently using

```
let description = container!.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
description!.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(storeRemoteChange(_:)),
                                       name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange,
                                       object: container!.persistentStoreCoordinator)

@objc
func storeRemoteChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    historyQueue.addOperation {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.container.viewContext.refreshAllObjects()
        }
    }
}

private lazy var historyQueue: OperationQueue = {
    let queue = OperationQueue()
     queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    return queue
}()
```

Comment: Core data objects are ObservableObjects hopefully you are observing them individually instead of forcing redraws with object will change. Also if you use FetchRequest you get the benefit of faulting. Only what is visible should redraw.

Comment: Hi, Yes I am observing them individually and not using objectWillChange. Neither `@FetchRequest` or `@ObservedObject` refresh derived attributes without additional code.

Comment: If you are using FerchRequest and ObservedObject for each core data object the impact of refreshing all objects should be minimal. If your UI is setup correctly it would just be the objects that are actively being presented.

Comment: Refreshing 100s of objects with `viewContext.refreshAllObjects()` versus refreshing 2 changed objects with `context.refresh()` should be an order of magnitude improvement, right? In practice I've seen significant improvement with this new approach when making bulk objects changes (>5  seconds) and avoiding a hang in instruments.

Comment: @JohnCashew Sounds like you've already found a good answer then. Good job!